# Chrome Remote Debugging - how to inspect elements in hybrid app (webview)

Tags: android, chrome-remote-debugging

I am trying to automate Gmail app for Android. In the "Compose" page, the part of the body of the message is a webview context. Using uiautomatorviewer i managed to retrieve the locator of the "body" element, but sending text to it - fails. Trying to switch context to "WEBVIEW" (i am using Appium) also fails. I wish to inspect elements in this page using chrome remote debugging. On my computer, i navigated to [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) and i launched the application on the android emulator. It looks alright.
[image]
But when i try to inspect elements, i see none.
[image]
What am i missing? (i made sure the to enable debugging and become a developer...)

Answer (score 0):

To enable WebView debugging `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` should be set on the WebView class. You need to make this change in your app code and rebuild it.

Following these [instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging?utm_campaign=2016q3&utm_medium=redirect&utm_source=dcc) was good enough for me

Comment: The app i am trying to automate is not my app, so i don't have access to the code of the app. As i wrote in my question, the app is Gmail for Android.

Comment: Then I don't see a way for you to make it work: it is expected to disable debugging in production builds, but for testing purpose you must have it turned on

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer and comment.

Comment: I think this will help @NisimNaim . I havnt tried it yet https://blog.speedfox.co.uk/articles/1524219174-android_webview_hackery/